# Absolute paths in react native version 0.72 typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, babeljs, absolute-path

Hey Guys so I'm struggling to set absolute paths in react native I used [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) for that and also set `tsconfig.json` and 'babel.config.js' as slowed below and VS code isn't giving any error about path but metro server throwing error like this

```
BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module @pages/pokemons/pokemons from D:\Work And Stydy Of IT\ReactNative\RTKTS\src\App.tsx: @pages/pokemons/pokemons could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
> 1 | import Pokemons from '@pages/pokemons/pokemons';
    |                       ^
  2 | import React from 'react';
  3 |
  4 | function App(): JSX.Element {
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\Work And Stydy Of IT\ReactNative\RTKTS\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\Work And Stydy Of IT\ReactNative\RTKTS\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
    at Object.resolve (D:\Work And Stydy Of IT\ReactNative\RTKTS\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:169:21)
    at Graph._resolveDependencies (D:\Work And Stydy Of IT\ReactNative\RTKTS\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:473:35)
    at Graph._processModule (D:\Work And Stydy Of IT\ReactNative\RTKTS\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:261:38)
    at async Graph._addDependency (D:\Work And Stydy Of IT\ReactNative\RTKTS\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:372:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at async Graph._processModule (D:\Work And Stydy Of IT\ReactNative\RTKTS\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:322:5)
    at async Graph._traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (D:\Work And Stydy Of IT\ReactNative\RTKTS\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:249:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

// tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@app": [
        "app/index"
      ],
      "@app/*": [
        "app/*"
      ],
      "@services": [
        "services/index"
      ],
      "@services/*": [
        "services/*"
      ],
      "@pages": [
        "pages/index"
      ],
      "@pages/*": [
        "pages/*"
      ],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        alias: {
          '@app': ['app/index'],
          '@app/*': ['app/*'],
          '@services': ['services/index'],
          '@services/*': ['services/*'],
          '@pages': ['pages/index'],
          '@pages/*': ['pages/*'],
          underscore: 'lodash',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Steps that I tried till now:

1. Delete `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` files and re install packages.
2. yarn start --reset-cache
3. Delete the old APK which is installed in an emulator.
4. again install everything.

Before posting this I tried a lot of answers which is available on Google and after that, I'm posting

Comment: How did you initialized your project?

Comment: @DineshMsd As normal npx react-native init projectName

Comment: can you initialize a new react native app with typescript and try? https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript

Comment: Make a note that babel-plugin-module-resolver was archived by the owner. I'm not sure it is a good idea to use it now.

Comment: @DineshMsd It's already new project react native 0.72.4 .

Comment: @Razi Okay, can you suggest me any other way around ? to active same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the TypeScript configuration file and the `babel.config.js` file needn't `index` route name, in my case both configurations were like the following examples:

```json
// tsconfig.json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@api": ["./api"], // this is for importing index file
      "@api/*": ["./api/*"], // this is for importing other files underneath of the api folder
```

```json
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: [
          '.ios.ts',
          '.ios.tsx',
          '.android.ts',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.ts',
          '.tsx',
          '.js',
          '.jsx',
          '.json',
        ],
        alias: {
          '@api': './src/api',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

These configurations are working for me.

Comment: I use same as you mentioned and it works thanks :)

Comment: @AnkitPatel, You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer put me in the right direction, but it's missing a few things.

I just started a React Native project from the CLI (`react-native: 0.73.1`). This is what worked for me:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "extends": "@react-native/typescript-config/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".", // <- can also use anything, e.g: ./src
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
            // "@api": ["./api"] <- would work the same
        }
    }
}
```

We need to install the `module-resolver` plugin:

```bash
npm install babel-plugin-module-resolver --save-dev
```

And add it to the Babel config:

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    presets: ["module:@react-native/babel-preset"],
    plugins: [
        [
            "module-resolver",
            {
                root: ["."], // <- this is the same as the baseUrl
                extensions: [
                    ".ios.ts",
                    ".ios.tsx",
                    ".android.ts",
                    ".android.tsx",
                    ".ts",
                    ".tsx",
                ],
                alias: {
                    "@": "./src/", // <- this is absolute (different from tsconfig)
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

After all this, you may run `npm start` and still see an `Error: Unable to resolve module`. If that's the case, run this command to reset the cache:

```bash
npm start -- --reset-cache
# or yarn start --reset-cache
```

A few notes:

- The `baseUrl` in the `tsconfig` should be the same as in `root` in the `babel.config`
- `alias` in `babel.config` only works with absolute paths, so:
  if you have in `tsconfig`: `"@/*": ["./src/*"]`
  you need to transform it to: `"@": "./src/"`

As a rule of thumb: remove `/*` from the key, remove `*` from the value.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was losing my mind on figuring this out and your answer finally did the trick.

Comment: Thanks! `yarn start --reset-cache` did the trick for me.